# Persist sub-menu on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to keep my sub-menu appearing when I hover onto it. Currently it disappears when I hover off `Locations`.

My Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/269yqavo/

Here is my code:

```js
$('.main a.primary').hover(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).next().toggle();
}).hover();
```

```css
.sub-menu {display:none;background:#ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li class="main">
      <a href="" class="primary">Locations</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="/location/athina/" title=
        "View all posts in Athina">Athina</a></li>

        <li><a href="/location/beirut/" title=
        "View all posts in Beirut">Beirut</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution without JS at all.
Simply show the sub menu whenever the container is hovered.

http://jsfiddle.net/269yqavo/1/

```
.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    background:#ccc
}

.main:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Without JS, sounds like a perfect solution to me :D

Comment: Despite the OP provided some JS, I personally think this is the cleverest solution because in any case, even if JS won't work for some unexpected reasons, the user will still be able to show the menu. Deserved +1.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do like this? The hover function should be used differently. The event should be bound on the parent.

```js
$('.main a.primary').parent().hover(function(e){
 $(this).find("a").next().show();
}, function () {
 $(this).find("a").next().hide();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {display: none; background: #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sf-menu">
  <li class="main">
    <a href="" class="primary">Locations</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="/location/athina/" title=
             "View all posts in Athina">Athina</a></li>
      <li><a href="/location/beirut/" title=
             "View all posts in Beirut">Beirut</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And instead of using JS, you can use CSS alone:

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  background: #ccc
}
.main:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sf-menu">
  <li class="main">
    <a href="" class="primary">Locations</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="/location/athina/" title=
             "View all posts in Athina">Athina</a></li>
      <li><a href="/location/beirut/" title=
             "View all posts in Beirut">Beirut</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how do u hold hover on Athina, Beirut?

Comment: @PrashantTapase Using the parent. Athina and Beirut are children of the LI. That's why.

Comment: @PrashantTapase On hovering on the `a`, it is obvious that we are hovering on the `li` too. Then on hovering `li`, the event handler for hover is added, and the menu inside that is shown. Well, it is same as your CSS code in JavaScript. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 0):

Why u do it by simple css?

HTML

```
<ul class="sf-menu">
    <li class="main">
      <a href="" class="primary">Locations</a>

      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="/location/athina/" title=
        "View all posts in Athina">Athina</a></li>

        <li><a href="/location/beirut/" title=
        "View all posts in Beirut">Beirut</a></li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
.sub-menu {display:none;background:#ccc}

.main:hover .sub-menu{
    display:block
}
```

> Simple logic here when u do hover on main class sub-menu will show

**[JSFIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/269yqavo/2/)**

OR

```
$('.sf-menu').children().hover(function(e){
    $(this).find("a").next().show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find("a").next().hide();
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/79r6hcgc/)**